# Latest Editor update - also reveals ".gs" as file type - what does this mean

Tags: editor, google-apps-script

I was just in the script editor. I noticed the ".gs" file type added
at the end of each file name.  Then I read the release notes.

The release notes indicated that a "scroll bar" was added to the "tree" file structure.
I was wondering if the revealing of the file type was a "slip", or is the file type going
to remain visible, from this point forward.

Is this be a sign that the script file (type ".gs) will become an independent
entry in the "create" menu for the Doclist screen, separate from spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From observations, the Google team usually release information after it's implemented. Last year some new features where announced during Google I/O. We may learn more after next weeks I/O conference :)